# Display center of image as width of div changes

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I have the following page where there's an image of piano keys inside the upper-left block, which is one of the 2x2 blocks in a container div. As you can see, the container is `nav-blocks`, and each of the blocks are `nav-block`. Inside of each block, there's the image, `nav-block-img`. Borders are there for illustration.

I want the following.

1. The image should expand across the entire width of the block as it is horizontally stretched. I gave `nav-block-img` `min-width:100%`. This works as I would like.
2. Once the block's width gets smaller than the width of the image, I would like the middle of the image to show, unlike in the screenshot where the image is "anchored" similar to `float:left`. If I `float:right`, then the image sticks out on the left side.

Is it possible to have the image be displayed in a "`float:center`" fashion, if it existed, so that each sides of the image stick out evenly as the div shrinks horizontally? I've tried several suggestions, but they don't seem to work in my framework.

```
.nav-blocks {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.nav-block {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
}
img.nav-block-img {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

[image: upper-left block]

Answer (score 0):

To center the image, just set

```
img.nav-block-img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that. I don't think it works. The image is still just as I have displayed in the main post.